# Error using "x expr" in "\addplot table" options

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have not been succesfull using `x expr` in `\addplot table` options, within Tikz/pgfplots. I don't think the problem is with the package being installed or not, because I have been using `\addplot table` for a long time.

See my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}


\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x index=0, y expr = \thisrowno{1}-1] {./antinumu/table_dm2_minimized.csv};
%
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Error message in Linux terminal:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/y expr' and I am going to
 ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 ...}-1] {./antinumu/table_dm2_minimized.csv};

? H
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

Comment: What version of PGFPlots are you using (check your `.log` file)?

Comment: In the log file: `pgfplots 2009/02/14 Version 1.2.2`

Comment: You have to update your PGFplots package, the current version is 1.9.

Comment: Ok, so here is the thing: I am on a integrated network (I don't know if the correct term is that) in the university, so I depend on what it is installed here. Knowing that, I have already tried extracting the file from sourceforge in a directory and typed in linux terminal the path to it: `TEXINPUTS=/home/pos/fcpenha/latex/pgfplots//:` But pdflatex seems to ignore it. The log file still says `Version 1.2.2`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to fix that. Probably best to either ask your IT help desk, or to open a new question.

Comment: Solved! The correct command to type on Linux terminal is `export TEXINPUTS=/home/pos/fcpenha/latex/pgfplots//:`. Thank you a lot, because I thought it was not about the version.

Comment: Glad it's working now!

Comment: Perhaps you should post your comment as an answer and accept it, to make it clearer that your question is answered?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is resolved by updating to a newer version of the package